# How to change # into %23 before inserting into database?

Tags: php, urlencode, hashtag

**This question has not been asked before.  That link above is no help.**

When trying to pass TXTurl variable in URL everything after the hashtag does not pass as the variable because it is a fragment.  I was doing some reading, and it the variable does pass as %23.  I have been trying to change the # to a %23 before it goes into the database.

I have tried urldecode() urlencode() - I have tried the below myUrlEncode function I found.

```
function myUrlEncode($TXTurl) {
    $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
    $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($TXTurl));
}


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO MyFAQlist (TXTurl, TXTlinkname) 
    VALUES (:TXTurl, :TXTlinkname)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':TXTurl', $TXTurl);
    $stmt->bindParam(':TXTlinkname', $TXTlinkname);
    myUrlEncode($TXTurl); 

    // insert a row 
    $TXTurl = "$TXTurl";
    // insert a row
    $TXTlinkname = "$TXTlinkname";
    $stmt->execute();
```

I want to replace # with %23 when inserting TXTurl into database.

Also Tried to use rawurlencode. ddint' work

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO MyFAQlist (TXTurl, TXTlinkname) 
VALUES (:TXTurl, :TXTlinkname)");
$stmt->bindParam(':TXTurl', $TXTurl);
$stmt->bindParam(':TXTlinkname', $TXTlinkname);
$TXTurl = rawurlencode($TXTurl);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'and have security'? This shouldn't be necessary for storing a url, especially when you use bind variables, like you do.

Comment: `rawurlencode()` is what you're looking for (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

Comment: I mean I want to avoid injections....

Comment: @JD Then you should properly prevent injections, using parameterized queries. There is **no risk** of SQL injections if you properly use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode them using `rawurlencode`:

```php
$url = 'http://my-url.com/with-a-hash#';
echo rawurlencode($url); // http%3A%2F%2Fmy-url.com%2Fwith-a-hash%23
```

PHP Documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: I have several inserts.  Do I input like so?
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO MyFAQlist (TXTurl, TXTlinkname) 
    VALUES (:TXTurl, :TXTlinkname)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':TXTurl', $TXTurl);
    $stmt->bindParam(':TXTlinkname', $TXTlinkname);
    $TXTurl = rawurlencode($TXTurl);